# How can MPI be used efficiently in a portion of code?

Tags: mpi

My application involves run `myfuns()` in a serial time execution. It calls `dothings(...)`, which has a object instances and others passing to it. This function involves a loop each does a breadth-first search and it is really time consuming. I have used OpenMP for the loop and it speed up just a little bit, not good enough. I am thinking of using MPI parallelism to get more processes to work on, but not sure how to use it in an efficient way for this portion of code embedded deep inside a sequential code.

```
void dothings (object obji...) {
   std::vector retvec;
   for (i = 0; i < somenumber; i++) {
     /* this function involves breadth first search using std:queue */
     retval = compute(obji, i);
     retvec.push_back(retval);
   }
}

/* myfuns() gets called in a sequential manner */
void myfuns() {
  dothings(objectInstance,...)
}
```

Comment: The first question, before thinking of parallel computing, is "how efficient is the code for the moment ?". For instance, in your code snippet, what would be the effect of using `reserve()`, something like `std::vector<object> retvec;retvec.reserve(somenumber);`, to avoid unnecessary reallocation ? It will be hard to answer your question without more details about your problem.  On a single node, i don't know whether MPI could be much more efficient than OpenMP or not.

Comment: @francis, thanks for the suggestion, I focus on the search.   But as you said, it is worthwhile to change all the places where need reallocation.